# Is it possible to hook into the WCF cache provider?

Tags: .net, wcf, caching, rest, .net-4.0

When a WCF REST service has caching enabled, the underlying code (of course) is not run on subsequent calls to the same URI. However, I'm wondering if there is a way we could hook into the caching provider to see the request coming in and then log it. This would be for analysis purposes or to track API usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF REST caching is done by ASP.NET caching module which is registered to handle `HttpApplication.ResolveRequestCache` and `HttpApplication.UpdateRequestCache` event. You just need to handle event before `ResolveRequestCache` (most suitable would be `BeginRequest`) and access request directly in `HttpContext.Current.Request` (you can use `InputStream` property to read pure HTTP request). These events are typically handled in Global.asax file.

Be aware that caching can happen on multiple levels - client can have data in its own cache, proxy server can cache data, etc. so not necessarily all request which use cached response will hit your server. You can control where the data can be cached by setting `Location` in cache profile.

Comment: Makes sense. I wasn't sure if the cache-lookup happened before any of the events in the HttpApplication` class. Now I know. I'll give that a try. If the content is cached upstream of the server then oh well, but this will allow us to capture everything that hits the server. Thanks.